# How to check if process is running

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("notepad");
Process p = pb.run();
System.out.println("Notepad is closed")
```

The code above will run fine and open up notepad. However the print statement will not print until I manually close the notepad window. This is because Java waits until the process is terminated. Is there anyway I can just open a process and check if the window has loaded?

Answer (score 1):

The ProcessBuilder.start() method will not halt program execution.

You can use just like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("notepad");
Process p = pb.start();
System.out.println("This will print right after notepad is launched.")
```

You can then use the process object to read any output from the program, kill the program, or halt program execution until it is finished.

Here is the reference page: [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exitValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()) like this:

```java
try {
// instead of 0 use the exit value of your started program to run some logic if it has failed
    if (p.exitValue() != 0) {
               
    }
} catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
    // expected, here the logic will jump to if the program is still running
}
```